# Stretch Game to Fit Screen Size and Maintain Coordinate System

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to create a game similar to this [tutorial](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/2y9ofc/java_2d_platformer_devlogtutorial_open_source/?st=j36mj015&sh=e44d2f45), where you can find the source code.  Within GameFrame, there is GamePanel.  Within GamePanel, there is StatsPanel and PlayPanel. GameFrame and GamePanel are 1280 by 640, and StatsPanel is 1280 by 40 at the top of GamePanel and PlayPanel is 1280 by 600 at the bottom of GamePanel.

However, I wish to make the game full screen, but I do not wish to change the coordinate system because of the variance involved with different screen sizes.  So here is my question: How can I stretch the game to fit the screen size and maintain the coordinate system reference?

I believe it may be possible render the game as an image and then scale that to fit the screen.  In this manner, I can still refer to the components within the 1280 by 640 bounding box.  I do not know where and how to implement this.

**What I have tried thus far (in reference to the tutorial's source code):**

***GameFrame (extends JFrame)***

Constructor:

```
this.setLocation((int)((Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth()-WIDTH)/2),
            ((int)(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight()-HEIGHT)/2));     
this.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
```

replaced with:

```
this.setLocation(0,0);
this.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
this.setUndecorated(true);
```

***GameManager(extends Thread)***

run() method:

```
gamePanel.repaintGame();
```

replaced with:

```
gamePanel.repaint();
```

***GamePanel(extends JPanel)***

repaintGame() method:

```
public void repaintGame(){
    playPanel.repaint();
}
```

replaced with paintComponent() method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    playPanel.repaint();
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1280, 640, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0, 1280, 640, null);
}
```

These changes did not stretch the game to fit the screen size.  While the GameFrame and the black GamePanel spans the screen size, StatsPanel and PlayPanel appear to remain in the 1280 by 640 bounding box.

I am not quite experienced in Java so please forgive any oversights I may have made.

**EDIT: Image after changes (Ignore terminal window):**

[image: Screenshot]

As commented on c0der's answer:

> My main issue is to maintain the coordinate system. For example, point (500, 300) is different in a 1920 by 1080 screen than its location in a 1280 by 640 screen. As such, I was wondering whether it would be possible to stretch GamePanel, along with its components StatsPanel and PlayPanel, across a full screen GameFrame as an image or some other means. That way, the point (500, 300) will always refer to the (500, 300) within GamePanel, and GamePanel will subsequently be stretched across the screen. I've uploaded a picture to my post. I wish to stretch the game to the screen size.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "With GameFrame, there is GamePanel. Within GamePanel, there is StatsPanel and PlayPanel. "-  I believe it describes a simple layout question, of a main panel in a JFrame, holding two nested JPanels. This is not related to a specific game. Consider posting [mcve] : this will make helping much easier (and will also help you to figure out a solution)

Comment: Is [this](http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/857005) a good representation of the current layout ?

Comment: I think it is a little bit more complex than a simple layout question because I also wish to maintain the coordinate system and the location of the sprites relative to PlayPanel.  I will consider posting a more complete, simple program later when I have the time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a good representation of the layout:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    public static final int WIDTH=1280;
    public static final int HEIGHT=640;

    public GameFrame(GamePanel gamePanel){

        //set frame to appear at the center of the screen
        this.setLocation((int)((Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth()-WIDTH)/2),
                ((int)(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight()-HEIGHT)/2));

        this.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        this.add(gamePanel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GameFrame(new GamePanel());
    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel{

    public static final int PLAY_PANEL_HEIGHT=640;
    public static final int STATS_HEIGHT=40;

    public GamePanel(){

        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        JPanel statsPanel= new JPanel();
        statsPanel.setSize(GameFrame.WIDTH, STATS_HEIGHT);
        statsPanel.setLayout(null);
        statsPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        statsPanel.setLocation(0, 0);
        this.add(statsPanel);

        JPanel playPanel=new JPanel();
        playPanel.setSize(GameFrame.WIDTH, PLAY_PANEL_HEIGHT);
        playPanel.setLayout(null);
        playPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        playPanel.setLocation(0, STATS_HEIGHT);
        this.add(playPanel);
    }
}
```

Make the changes as explained in the comments to make it full screen:

```
public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    public GameFrame(GamePanel gamePanel){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        this.add(gamePanel);

        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true); //make sure you have means to close the window
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GameFrame(new GamePanel());
    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel{

    public static final int STATS_HEIGHT=40;

    public GamePanel(){

        //using null layout manager requires that you manually handle all size or
        //other layout changes. a much better practice is to use layout manager
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());//use BorderLayout instead of null
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        JPanel statsPanel= new JPanel();
        //width is ignored for NORTH components of BorderLyayout
        statsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, STATS_HEIGHT));
        statsPanel.setLayout(null);
        statsPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        this.add(statsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel playPanel=new JPanel();
        //height is ignored for CENTER components of BorderLyayout
        playPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, 0));
        playPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.add(playPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Stretching an image means either make each pixel bigger, which you don't control, or, in your case, adding pixels. 
Adding pixels will obviously change `(500,300)` coordinates (as an example) to something else. 
I see two options:

a. Keep `GamePanel` at a fixed size, regardless of the frame size. 

b. Calculate the coordinates dynamically based on actual size, rather than use fixed values like `(500,300)`. 

I would recommend option b.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried your code, but I think you misunderstood my question.  My main issue is to maintain the coordinate system.  For example, point (500, 300) is different in a 1920 by 1080 screen than its location in a 1280 by 640 screen.  As such, I was wondering whether it would be possible to stretch GamePanel, along with its components StatsPanel and PlayPanel, across a full screen GameFrame as an image or some other means.  That way, the point (500, 300) will always refer to the (500, 300) within GamePanel, and GamePanel will subsequently be stretched across the screen.

Comment: I've uploaded a picture to my post.  I wish to stretch the game to the screen size.